# Matching stacked items sizes in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have the following `Grid`.

```
 <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
     <Border HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" CornerRadius="4" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkBrushKey}}">
         <Border.RenderTransform>
             <TranslateTransform X="2" Y="2" />
         </Border.RenderTransform>
         <Border.BitmapEffect>
             <BlurBitmapEffect Radius="4" />
         </Border.BitmapEffect>
     </Border>
     <Grid Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}">
         <Image Source="{Binding Image}"></Image>
     </Grid>
 </Grid>
```

It renders like this.

[image: Sample]

Notice the first one is horizontal while the other is vertical.

How do I tell the `Border` to be the same size as the inner `Grid`? This is so that I can match the drop shadow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try the follows:

```
<Grid DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
     <Border HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" CornerRadius="4" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkBrushKey}}"
Width="{Binding ElementName=G, Path=ActualWidth}"
Height="{Binding ElementName=G, Path=ActualHeight}"
     >
         <Border.RenderTransform>
             <TranslateTransform X="2" Y="2" />
         </Border.RenderTransform>
         <Border.BitmapEffect>
             <BlurBitmapEffect Radius="4" />
         </Border.BitmapEffect>
     </Border>
     <Grid x:Name="G" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}">
         <Image Source="{Binding Image}"></Image>
     </Grid>
 </Grid>
```

Cheers

Comment: Thanks. That worked great other than I had to bind to the `Image`.

Comment: Do you know why if I have the whitebackground on the grid, it clips the right hand side of the shadow?

Comment: Probably because the grid and the border have the same exact width. Anyway, I am not sure to mean the effect. Could you post a snapshot?

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted works fine for me, the border size matches the inner Grid's size, because they are both stretched to fit the Outer Grid's Size.

If your outer Grid is a set size no matter what, and your inner Image is a variable size, you might want to consider moving your Border into the Inner Grid and setting it's Horizontal/Vertical alignment to Center so it doesn't stretch to fill it's contents

```
<Grid DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
     <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}">

          <Border HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" CornerRadius="4" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkBrushKey}}">
              <Border.RenderTransform>
                  <TranslateTransform X="2" Y="2" />
              </Border.RenderTransform>
              <Border.BitmapEffect>
                  <BlurBitmapEffect Radius="4" />
              </Border.BitmapEffect>
          </Border>

         <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Height="150" Width="150"></Image>
     </Grid>
 </Grid>
```

Comment: The blur is being applied. I don't want the blur on the `Image`.

Comment: @Daniel Can't you set a `Margin` to offset the border from the Image by a bit?

Comment: @Daniel Nevermind, I see what you mean. The code you posted works fine for me, the border size matches the inner Grid's size, because they are both stretched to fit the Outer Grid's Size. If your outer Grid is a set size no matter what, you might want to consider nesting another Grid between the inner and outer one that is allowed to size to it's children's content (Set Horizontal/Vertical Alignment to Center)